# Error in setFragment - FB-Native Login

Tags: android, facebook, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

i am using Facebook Nativelogin , so that it would be faster than traditional method but i get the error as below (image) ,

[image]

Actually `this` pointer points to the current Fragment here , is that right ? if not , 
what does this `this` pointer points to ? and why i get this error ? i dont know where i am going wrong .

I am following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#protip1

and http://code.google.com/p/app-container/source/browse/trunk/AppContainer/src/levelrewind/android/app/FacebookFragment.java?spec=svn237&r=237

but i get the same error i have searched a lot but there are only a few threads about the native FB login and i have went through all those threads but i was not successful

Comment: What class is your code in? the error from Eclipse seems to suggest that you're calling setFragment from MainActivity, rather than a Fragment subclass.

Comment: i get the same error even if i code this in Fragment subclass .

Comment: Please post full code. There's really no way to debug this without more information.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up , and i changed the methods completely and now following different link . Actually i changed nothing from the link i posted above , but i was getting this error .

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same problem. I am fairly certain this is because the Facebook 3.0 API uses the android support library fragment and so you have to do the same i.e.

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

and the problem is resolved. However, there may be other implications that you need to address as a consequence of making this change.

Comment: I'm hoping *not* to use v4 support library (damn FB!) is there a workaround? By getting the current fragment's context?

Answer (score 1):

if you dig in the LoginButton class you will notice that the facebook sdk is using

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

I can only assume that you are using

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

so you need to use the Fragment provided by the support library

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but was able to resolve it.

If you go to LoginButton.java under the widget package in the facebook library you may see that the setFragment function has an error on the Fragment object. It has something to do with  the version of the support library facebook is using and your project is using. In Android Studio I was able to resolve it by hovering over the error and selecting the option to add that version of the support library to my class path.

Answer (score 0):

If your IDE says that `this` is refering to an instance of `MainActivity`, I am pretty sure that your methods are misplaced.

You have to create a `Fragment` in your `MainActivity` and move your `onCreateView()` method in this fragment. Doing this way, you will refer to an instance of `Fragment` writing `authButton.setFragment(this);`.